# React/Mobx: Selecting item in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, mobx

What would be the most efficient approach to handle selecting items from an `array`. Let's asume the interface is defined in a different domain, so you could extend the interface, but not alter it.

Here are two approaches I have thought off:

a) Add a flag to the item, e.g. a `selected` property

```js
interface Item extends OriginalItem {
  selected: boolean
}

class ItemsStore {
  public items: Item[]
  
  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)
  }

  public toggleItem(item, checked) {
     const storedItem = this.items.find(i => i.id === item.id)
     if (storedItem) {
         storedItem.selected = checked 
     }
  }
}
```

b) Add an additional observable, e.g. `selectedItems`

```js
class ItemsStore {
  public items: Item[]
  public selectedItems: Item[]
  
  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)
  }

  public toggleItem(item, checked) {
     const selectedIndex = this.selectedItems.findIndex(i => i.id === item.id)
     if (checked && selectedIndex === -1) {
       this.selectedItems.push(item)
     } else if (!checked && selectedIndex !== -1) {
       this.selectedItems.splice(selectedIndex, 1)
     }
  }
}
```

NOTE: I know adding and filtering-out could be done in a more functional programming manner, and to be honest I do not know what approach suits *Mobx*, but this part is not that important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First approach with `selected` property is much simpler and is more "mobx way" of doing things. It also does not change the array of items, so for example if you have list component with `.map` it won't rerender extra time.

And if you need `selectedItems` you can just add `computed` getter which will only be recomputed when something changes:

```
class ItemsStore {
  public items: Item[]
  
  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)
  }

  public toggleItem(item, checked) {
     const storedItem = this.items.find(i => i.id === item.id)
     if (storedItem) {
         storedItem.selected = checked 
     }
  }

  // Will become optimised computed property
  get selectedItems() {
    return this.items.filter(item => item.selected)
  }
}
```